# Reference links and footnotes

Tags: discussion, reference

In my posts I prefer to post reference material and links if possible to sources. Is this not necessary or does that make for a more proper answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're Jon Skeet (which is The Source<sup>©</sup>) it is always better to include references to official documentation, extensive blog-posts, articles, videos or training material because it enables others

- to verify the correctness of your answer
- to gain more in-depth or wider knowledge about the orginal problem
- to learn where to look the next time if anyone encounters  a similar problem

By adding the sources you used to be able to answer the question teaches the OP and the visitors of the question how to fish which is a better survival technique than just handing over the prepared fish-and-chips.

Answers that teaches how to fish deserves upvotes.

[Here is post about how to handle questions that ask for fish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32716/feeding-them-vs-teaching-to-fish)
[And here is an answer how to handle answers that only present fish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184721/158100)

Comment: Great, and thank you for the additional material!